# Is there an equivalent command for kctune | grep max_thread_proc in SunOS and AIX?

Tags: solaris, aix, solaris-10

I need to find the maximum threads per processor in the following systems. So far

```
1. Redhat Linux         -> cat /proc/sys/kernel/threads-max
2. HPUX 11.31 [ia64]    -> kctune | grep max_thread_proc
3. Solaris 10 [ SPARC ] ->  ??
4. AIX 6.1(TL5)         ->  ??
```

Please help me find out for Solaris and AIX.

Answer (score 0):

AIX's is in the file /etc/security/limits. Say you wanted to work with the root user, and limit / set the number of threads per processor. The file is made up of stanzas:

```
root:
    fsize = -1
    core = -1
    cpu = -1
    data = -1
    rss = -1
    stack = -1
    nofiles = -1
    threads = 1024
```

Threads per processor is now set to 1024 (-1 means unlimited). To verify this is working, log in as root and type in:

```
ulimit -a
```

You should see threads show up as 1024.

Comment: i do not have root permission, though I got a solution thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found these

```
AIX     -> getconf -a | grep PTHREAD_THREADS_MAX
SOLARIS -> getconf -a | grep PTHREAD_THREADS_MAX
```